# Finding all members of a Distribution List

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

We want to find all members of a DL, but it's become bloated with DL's inside of DL's, is there a way to expand all of these without needed to hit the '+' a few hundred times?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I found out my company had a very old system that works around this fault in DL's. A coworker showed it to me, our support center wasn't aware it was still operational...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of system. In a domain environment where you have elevated privileges, you can run a simple Dsquery that produces a list of all members and member-members. The whole hierarchy. More info here at Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/49405/command-line-to-list-users-in-a-windows-active-directory-group